# How can I concatenate a string and a variable which is types of int?

Tags: c, concatenation

I have to write a macro which concatenate a variable that hold a number with GPIO.
For example:

```
 #define SELECT_PIN(pin) GPIO##pin

int main (void)
{
  uint16_t x=5;
  ioregister.SELECT_PIN(x)= OUTPUT;
}
```

This macro naturally output the result like **"this structure has no element like GPIOx"** .

I need your helps guys.

Comment: You wan't be able to use macro for that. `x` is variable which changes during run-time, macros are expanded during compile time. You either need to make your `x` a macro as well, or use run-time functions to convert integer to string and concatenate a string.

Comment: This is not a complete [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SergeyA Okey sir, I forgot that macros executes at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I concatenate a string and a variable which is types of int?

You cannot. You may convert an `int` to a string and concatenate - using `snprintf`.

> I have to write a macro which concatenate a variable that hold a number with GPIO

That is not possible - macro has to execute at compile time in preprocessor - it can't depend on a value of a variable.

---

You can write a function.

```
void pin_set(register_type reg, uint16_t idx, bool value) {
     if (idx == 0) {
         reg.GPIO0 = val;
     } else .... etc. ..
}

bool pin_get(register_type reg, uint16_t idx) {
    ... similar to above ...
}

int main() {
  uint16_t x=5;
  pin_set(ioregister, x, OUTPUT);
}
```

Typically `GPIOX` are some convenience struct members defined inside an union and such `set` and `get` functions use bit masks to do the operation on the other struct member that allows to access whole register as one word.

Comment: I thought that implement functions like you wrote but, there are 87 pins. I am trying to get used C2000 series from TI and TI only offers .h header files that includes register definition within nested union-structures. This nested build makes things hard. ST was best..